# Parse html failed with BeautifulSoup and requests, I can't figure it out, can anyone tell me why?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
r = requests.get(self.url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print r.content # Here, I got output of the html
print soup.text # Here, I can't get any output, which puzzled me.
```

It may be what reason/reasons caused this?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

Because the BS didn't parse the document correctly, so it lost some content.

The solution is:

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')